# Q: joint density $P(x, y)$ when $Y=X^2+Z$ and $X, Z$ are uniformly distributed.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function

$Y=X^2+Z$, $X$ and $Z$ are uniformly distributed.
$$
P(x)=\frac12 I_{\{-1<x<1\}}, \\
P(z)=10 I_{\{0<z<1/10\}}\\
P(x,y)={}?
$$
How can I solve it?

**X and Z are independent

Comment: It's often easier to work with the cumulative functions than with the density functions (the correct thing to do is more intuitive). Have you tried that? Besides that, what kinds of theorems do you have about transforming random variables? For instance, what's the probability function for $X^2$?

Comment: Only thing I know is that X and Z are uniformly distributed. I guess I can solve it if I use cumulative function (or distribution fuction) but I don't know how.

Comment: The question does not have an answer unless you impose some independence assumptions.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write X and Z are independent.